# I can't login sandbox user on simulator - incorrect pass/user

Tags: ios, xcode

I created a new sandbox user for the pay test. I validated Email no problem so far. After that, I tried login on IOS(11) simulator(IPhoneX) but has an error:

> "incorrect username or password"

I'm sure email and passwords correct.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Just solved this by logging in with my new sandbox user at icloud.com and agreeing to their T&Cs. Simulator login then works a charm!

Comment: Thank you - this still works like a charm! <3

Comment: Amazing! [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12689078/alex-price)  yes it working as well by following you. :D

Comment: Still works great in 2023 :)

Comment: Apple should show a different error than "incorrect username or password" :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks

Comment: it still works thanks

Comment: you are a true life saver  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, make sure that the storekit config is selected as an option in the Run Settings:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting-up-storekit-testing-in-xcode/

The config file was in the project but not linked. Took a while to figure out this was the issue.