# AppReview Rejected Sandbox Account Test Email Subscription Because "Can't Connect to AppStore - Retry"

Tags: ios, xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

On my purchase page I use RevenueCat to make the initial purchase and in my SettingsVC I have the in-app purchase API (as required) to later resubscribe:

```
// ...
try await AppStore.showManageSubscriptions(in: window as! UIWindowScene)
```

I followed these [directions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59680742/4833705) and these [directions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77428131/4833705). Using an iPhone 8 simulator I logged into iCloud as a sandbox tester eg. sandboxtest@test.com, then logged into its Settings, loaded my app, made a purchase, the subscription went through and eventually expired. While in the iPhone 8 I checked my SettingsVC > in-app purchase API and it said `Expired Nov 5, 2023 ... Select an option to resubscribe`. So it worked. I send sandboxtest@test.com and the pw to App Review and got the below rejection:

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app. Specifically, your app
> displayed an error page when the Mange Subscription tab was tapped. We
> found that while you have submitted in-app purchase products for your
> app, the in-app purchase functionality is not present in your binary.
> If you would like to include in-app purchases in your app, you will
> need to upload a new binary that incorporates the in-app purchase API
> to enable users to make a purchase

They sent me a screenshot and the in-app purchase API said `Cannot Connect - Retry`.

I later use my actual device and try these 3 ways:

1- While logged in as myself, without using any Sandbox Account, delete the app, run it again, then log into my app with sandboxtest@test.com

2- While logged in as myself, use a different sandbox tester such as whatever@test.com to log into the Sandbox Account, delete the app, run it again, then log into my app with sandboxtest@test.com

3- While logged in as myself, use sandboxtest@test.com for the Sandbox Account, delete the app, run it again, then log into my app with sandboxtest@test.com

For all 3 RevenueCat prints the initial subscription and the expiration date, but for some reason when I go to the in-app purchase API, it always returns `You do not have any subscriptions`.

What's strange is when I go back to the iPhone 8 while still logged in as sandboxtest@test.com, the in-app purchase API still shows `Expired Nov 5, 2023 ... Select an option to resubscribe`.

I'm kinda lost here because to use an actual device to login, it sends a SMS, so I don't see how giving the App Reviewer the sandboxtest@test.com/pw info to login into the device and iCloud will help him/her make a purchase because they can't get the SMS. I would assume they would only need sandboxtest@test.com, but that does't work for them.

**Any advice?**

Comment: Test with a TestFlight build. You can then use your real App Store account to test (but you won't be charged)

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks :). Rejection before this one was `We are not able to continue our review because we need access to a demo account with an expired subscription to review the entire purchase flow.` The only way I found to speed up the subscriptions was https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730115 and https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704214?answerId=710545022#710545022. Using my real device even while logged in as a test user only returned the normal expiration date. What expiration date will I get in TestFlight?

Comment: TestFlight is like production, so it does not have accelerated expiration.

Comment: @Paulw11 that's horrible. I have a 2 week trial period. So that means I have to wait at least 2 weeks before I can send it back to AppReview. There has to be some way around that. Some apps have a 1 - 3 month trial period.

Comment: Can't you set up a user in your database with an "expired subscription" so that your app shows that the user needs to resubscribe; Apple can use their own App Store account to resubscribe

Comment: I was under the impression that the in-app purchase API manages all the subscriptions. Even if I `set up a user in your database with an "expired subscription" so that your app shows that the user needs to resubscribe`, when Apple presses the button to get the in-app purchase API to appear, it will show that the user either never made a purchase or the purchase is still valid (assuming I actually made a test purchase then did what you suggested). On a side note, what I did was deleted my 2 week introductory offer and created a new 3 day introductory offer. After they test I can change it back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255877/discussion-between-lance-samaria-and-paulw11).